# Elasticsearch 1.3.2 intermittently gives NoNodeException

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using Java Transport Client to connect to Elasticsearch cluster. Both the cluster and client are at version 1.3.2. I intermittently get the following NoNodeAvailableException.

NoNodeAvailableException : None of the configured nodes were available: ...{data=false, master=false}])

This is how I am connecting via the Transport Client. I intentionally increased the Ping Timeout interval to avoid this issue, but without much luck. Any thoughts what else can be done to prevent this exception ?

```
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
                    .put("cluster.name", cluster)
                    .put("client.transport.ping_timeout", "20s")
                    .build();
this.client =
        new TransportClient(settings).addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(host, port));
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 changes

1. Network flakiness - The network would be flaky and is not allowing
   intermittent connections.
2. GC - When garbage collection is triggered , there would be a span of
   "stop the world" time. In this span the java process will freeze and
   the node would give the same "No node exception". Watch the GC
   activities of the nodes to see if this is the cause.
3. Client and Server Elasticsearch version - See if both of them are
   the same

Answer (score 0):

Increased the ping timeout and added the following config changes inspired from http://petabyte-georgesanchez.blogspot.com/2014/07/elasticsearch-sniff-sniff.html and it seems to be working fine.

.put("client.transport.sniff", true)
.put("client.transport.ping_timeout", "25s")                            .put("client.transport.nodes_sampler_interval", "10s")